# How do I configure Apache's sites-enabled config?

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have a UBUNTU/APACHE box, when I try to get to the web server using the HOST-NAME it gets me to the DocumentRoot (which is /var/www) and shows me all the files/folders there (as expected).

In my /var/www I have a few folders such as /var/www/devel and var/www/live, how can I update my config so that when I hit the server through its host-name [http://servername] it goes into a sub folder of the DocumentRoot by default.

I tried to change DocumnetRoot to point to /var/www/live, this works when I hit the host-name it sends me to the correct path, however I cannot then access /var/www/dev (by going to [http://servername/dev]).

This is most likely because now /dev is outside DocumentRoot, how can I adjust the config so that I can still get to [http://servername/dev] while [http://servername] resolves to /live.

Here is my config...

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/dev">
            AuthName "NTLM Authentication"
            NTLMAuth on
            NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
            NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
            AuthType NTLM
            require valid-user
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/live">
            AuthName "NTLM Authentication"
            NTLMAuth on
            NTLMAuthHelper "/usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-ntlmssp"
            NTLMBasicAuthoritative on
            AuthType NTLM
            require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't change the DocumentRoot if you want the behavior you describe. What you need to do is redirect using something like mod_rewrite to "rewrite" that one url to point to the dir you need. That way you still have the DocumentRoot preserved. Its going to look something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ /live/ [R]
```

Check this link out for some more ideas.
[Redirects](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/remapping.html)